# How can I teach Gengar a skill to make enemies fall asleep?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I'm trying to find a way to have my Gengar (both in Pokemon Sapphire Alpha or X) to learn a skill to make other Pokemon fall asleep.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gengar Learns **Hypnosis** at Lv.1.

If you already have a levelled Gengar, go to the *Move Relearner* in either of the games to relearn Hypnosis.

**XY** - Move Relearner is in the house north-east of the Pokémon Center in Dendemille Town.

**ORAS** - Move Reminder in the house in the north-west of Fallarbor Town.

You need *1 Heart Scale* to remember moves.

Comment: thanks! do you know where is in pokemon alpha?

Comment: ORAS - stands for Omega Ruby/Alpha Saphire. Which in your case is Alpha Saphire

Comment: ah ok lol, sorry :)

Comment: @FezVrasta From a competitive standpoint, Hypnosis isn't that great of a move due to its low accuracy. If you're building a Gengar for competitive reasons, it might be better to to leave the Sleep to another Pokemon, and let Gengar do what it does best - sweep with its array of high power, good coverage Special-Attacks

Comment: ah umh... yes probably you are right

Comment: @Robotnik probably he wants to exploit "Shadow Tag" ability of MegaGengar, with its high Base Speed and a bit of luck you can then sweep several Pokemon